# Cannot read property 'join' of undefined in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

My url link is like so http://localhost:50255/product/filter/manufacturer/3

and on document load, i try to set the `manufacturer 3` value like so

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var pathname = window.location.pathname.split("/");
    var filter = pathname[pathname.length-3];
            if(filter === 'filter'){
                var option = pathname[pathname.length-2];
                var id = pathname[pathname.length-1];
                $("#ManufacturerID").val(id).trigger("change");
            }
        });
```

but i get the error

> Cannot read property 'join' of undefined

My html markup is

```
  <div class="select2-container select2-container-multi js-example-basic-multiple col-sm-12" id="s2id_ManufacturerID" style="border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902); display: block;">
         <ul class="select2-choices">  
           <li class="select2-search-field">    
           <label for="s2id_autogen6" class="select2-offscreen"></label>    
           <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input select2-default" id="s2id_autogen6" placeholder="" style="width: 1004px;">  
           </li>
         </ul>
       <div class="select2-drop select2-drop-multi select2-display-none select2-drop-active">   
         <ul class="select2-results">   
           <li class="select2-no-results">No matches found</li>
         </ul>
       </div>
    </div>


    <select id="ManufacturerID" class="js-example-basic-multiple col-sm-12" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Κατασκευαστές" style="border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902); display: none;" tabindex="-1">
         <option value="1">manufacturer 1</option>
         <option value="2">manufacturer 2</option>
         <option value="3">manufacturer 3</option>
    </select>
```

What am i doing wrong here?

**UPDATE** thanks to the comments, the error comes from the following function

```
$(function () {
            $('select').select2()
            .on("change", function (e) {
                var id = '#sel' + $(this).attr("id");
                var array = e.val.join(",");
                $(id).val(array);
                PostIt();
            })
        });
```

Comment: I don't believe the JS code you've posted is producing the error you're experiencing. The error is suggesting you're trying to read a property called `join` on an object which is `undefined`. However nothing in your code shows where you are trying to read this `join` property or from which object.

Comment: You're triggering a change event, do you have a change handler on that element that might be throwing the error?

Comment: @wing Saved me about a day of searching. Now i have to figure out why the e.val is undefined :)

Comment: @JaredSmith Without your help i would still be searching. Can you please check the update?

Comment: @OrElse glad to be of help. Looks like Zoheiry got it for you. In the future don't forget that if all else fails (or right from the start) you can `grep` the directory for an idiom like '.join' and as long as you don't have a gagillion joins its pretty simple to figure out which is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that `e.val` is undefined. Try replacing it with `e.target.value`